# Evaluation of multiple conditions combined using AND in a single if statement

Tags: if-statement, haskell

In languages such as C++, if there are multiple conditions in an "if" statement, and the conditions are combined with using AND (i.e., &&) then as soon as one of the conditions is false, the evaluation of the subsequent conditions do not happen. Is this also true for Haskell?
For example, in the Haskell code below, of conditionA is FALSE, will the evaluation of conditionB happen?

```
fun :: Haxl (Maybe Bool)
fun =
 if conditionA .&& conditionB
    then return $ Just True
    else return Nothing
```

Answer (score 4):

This is true in Haskell. `&&` is defined like so:

```
False && _ = False
True  && y = y
```

Which is equivalent to the following:

```
(&&) x y = case x of
  False -> False
  True -> y
```

Lazy evaluation in Haskell is defined in terms of `case`: when you evaluate a pattern-match on something, it’s *forced* (evaluated) as far as necessary to determine the constructor to match. So this is automatically short-circuiting.

This is generally true *everywhere* in Haskell. For example, `foldr (&&) True [True, True, False, error "not reached"]` evaluates `True && True && True && False && error "not reached"`, which returns `False` immediately after evaluating `False`, never evaluating the `error` call.

In addition, due to laziness, in Haskell you can always assign an expression to a variable, and it will not change what is evaluated. For example, these are exactly equivalent:

```
example1 x = cheapTest x || expensiveTest x
```

```
example2 x =
  let
    okay = cheapTest x
    cool = expensiveTest x
  in
    okay || cool

-- or:

example2 x = okay || cool
  where
    okay = cheapTest x
    cool = expensiveTest x
```

`expensiveTest` will not be called unless `cool` is evaluated, which will only happen if `okay` is `False`. This is unlike an eagerly evaluated language, where this may change runtime cost, or a non–referentially transparent language, where it may change side effects. For example, in JavaScript, `example1` and `example2` differ:

```
function cheapTest(x) {
  console.log('cheap test');
  return x !== 0;
}

function expensiveTest(x) {
  console.log('expensive test');
  return Math.log2(x) < 10;
}

// Short-circuits second effect if possible.
function example1(x) {
  return cheapTest(x) || expensiveTest(x);
}

// Always evaluates both effects.
function example2(x) {
  var okay = cheapTest(x);
  var cool = expensiveTest(x);
  return okay || cool;
}
```

**However**, the example you show, from the [`haxl`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haxl) package, is *not* the standard `&&` operator in Haskell’s standard library, but is using a different custom operator called `.&&`, which is defined like this:

```
fa .&& fb = do a <- fa; if a then fb else return False
```

So this is specifying the same kind of short-circuiting for the custom `GenHaxl` action type that the library defines. First this function executes the action `fa`, which produces a `Bool` assigned to `a`, then only if `a` is `True` does it execute the next action `fb`. If `a` is `False`, it just runs the action `return False` (= `pure False`), which performs no side effects and produces `False`.

Haxl also uses the `RebindableSyntax` extension to override `if`…`then`…`else`… syntax to allow side effects in the `if` condition. In normal Haskell code without that extension, you would need to separate the effects from the `if`, for example, using a separate binding statement in a `do` block:

```
fun = do
  c <- conditionA .&& conditionB
  if c
    then return $ Just True
    else return Nothing

  -- or: return $ if c then Just True else Nothing
```